# При копировании текста копирует стиль

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый вечер уважаемые знатоки. Сегодня случайно обнаружил на своём сайте ошибку. При копировании текста в форму `contenteditable=true`, кроме текста копируются также и какие-то `html` теги. Притом в каждом браузере один и тот же скопированный текст, копируется с разными тегами. В одном браузере вставляются теги `SPAN`, в другом браузере вставляются `BR`. Как решают эту проблему профессионалы? Неужели придётся с помощью `JS` очищать весь текст от лишних тегов?

Comment: Ссылку на пациента можно?

Comment: (текста в форму) что за форма, form input? если да - зачем(contenteditable=true) ; (При копировании) может при вставке? ; html не помешает

Comment: qwabra, как вы могли догадаться, форма представляется из себя редактируемый DIV.

Comment: Профессионалы берут любой готовый WYSIWYG-редактор и не используют contenteditable напрямую

Comment: andreymal, неужели нет другого способа сделать это самостоятельно, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Можно конечно, только замучаетесь

Comment: andreymal, танки грязи не боятся. Опишите пожалуйста в общих чартах как это делается. Всё остальное я смогу сделать сам.

Comment: @StasHappy а чем не угодил textarea? если вы копируете из Word или контент с html страниц в редактируемый div, то ни чего удивительного нет в том, что вы видите все скопированные теги.

Comment: Андрей ProjectSoft, вы правы. По большому счёту я бы конечно остановился на TEXTAREA, но попросили добавить возможность отправления смайликов. Пришлось заменить TEXTAREA на редактируемый DIV, чтобы иметь возможность вставлять в текст IMG-смайлики (как Вконтакте). Но одновременно с этим возникла проблема с этими лишними HTML тегами в тексте.

Comment: @StasHappy почитайте код какого-нибудь ckeditor

Comment: вы текст который копируете для начала вставьте в обычный виндовый блокнот и сохраните -> закройте и потом открывайте и копируйте куда угодно

Comment: @Максим Ленский, более того, давайте я сделаю пометку для всех пользователей сайта, чтобы каждый раз при копировании текста, они обязательно имели под рукой блокнот. )))))